# Does google bot read the tool tip box content and does it benefit having it, in terms of seo?

Tags: seo, google

Does google bot read the tool tip box content and does it benefit having it, in terms of seo?

I have seen SE using this on homepage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google threw up this article about alt and title attributes and how Google reads them: http://ezinearticles.com/?Do-Alt-and-Title-Attributes-Help-With-SEO?&id=432783

Comment: Nice article - I would add that this implies that is how the tool-tips are getting generated.  If itpian.com made their tool tips in JavaScript then results could vary.

Comment: good point I assumed they were title or alt atttibutes